# Pass typed Text Value to API call Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using TypeAheadFormField to show Text suggestions when a user types, for example, user types 'Lon' and my API will return 'London' as a suggestion.

My API call needs the letters typed to make the call and autosuggest results close to the users typed value.

My API URL requires those letters types to be part of the `String` for the `RestAPI` Call (i.e. ...&q=london&apikey=x)

Is there a way to pass the typed `textValue` recognised by the `TypeAheadFormField` to the `suggestionsCallback:` method to then use in the call?

TextAhead registers the typed Text to show results but I'm unsure how to make it a var, for example.

```
TypeAheadFormField<Item?>(
  textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
    autofocus: true,
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder()
    )
  ),
  suggestionsCallback: 

 *API is called here* MapItemsExample.getUserSuggestions,
 
  itemBuilder: (context, Item? suggestion) {
...
```

Call

```
  static FutureOr<Iterable<auto.Item>> getUserSuggestions(String query) async {
    

    final url = Uri.parse('https_call');
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userss = json.decode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> users = userss["items"];

      return users.map((json) => auto.Item.fromJson(json)).where((user) {
        final nameLower = user.title!.toLowerCase();
        final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
        return nameLower.contains(queryLower);
      }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

Thank you

**Update**

I have changed the URL call to this

```
          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
            final url = Uri.parse('https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=lat,long&q=$query&apiKey=my_key');
            final response = await http.get(url);
```

There are no errors now except the `query` parameter.

How do I make the `$query` in the URL call the Text of whichever letters have been entered by the user, as they type? Thanks

Comment: You want to add query parameter to request url. So, You should do like this.
`final queryParameters = { 'q': query,
  'apikey': 'xxxxx',
};` then
`final uri =
    Uri.https('www.myurl.com', '/path/to/url', queryParameters);`

Comment: Yes I know how to do that, my question is how to extract the Text Value from the input field of TypeAheadField

Comment: I think the value is typed is in the `query` parameter. Also I think you can assign an TextEditingController. You can see example 2 in https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead#material-example-2

Comment: Thanks for your example, I had already tried that but couldn't get a result out of it. Is it meant to print a String in ```onSuggestionSelected:```?

Comment: `onSuggestionSelected` called when you select 1 item. To show your server requests, user starts typing, then you should call API in `suggestionsCallback`. In this method you should return List of something. When user select one of them (List) the selected item is sent to `onSuggestionSelected`. You should set it into `TextEditingController` value to show to user.

Comment: Thank you, do you have a code example? I am new-ish to Flutter so any code translation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I provide an example. In this example you read users when you type and this is got from server. Then, user selects one of them its values save in `TextEditController`

```dart
 this._typeAheadController.text = suggestion;
 // you can save in user here
 this._user = suggestion;
```

You can validate or anything else in `flutter_typeahead`

```dart
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final TextEditingController _typeAheadController = TextEditingController();
dynamic _user;

//...

Form(
  key: this._formKey,
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[       
        TypeAheadFormField(
          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
            controller: this._typeAheadController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'User'
            )
          ),          
          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
            final url = Uri.parse('https_call', { 'q': query,   'apikey': 'xxxxx', });
            final response = await http.get(url);

           if (response.statusCode == 200) {
             Map<String, dynamic> userss = json.decode(response.body);
             List<dynamic> users = userss["items"];

             return users.map((json) => auto.Item.fromJson(json)).where((user) {
             final nameLower = user.title!.toLowerCase();
             final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
             return nameLower.contains(queryLower);
             }).toList();
            } else {
             throw Exception();
           }
          },
          itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(suggestion),
            );
          },        
          onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
            this._typeAheadController.text = suggestion;
            // you can save in user here
            this._user = suggestion;
          },         
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Submit'),
          onPressed: () {
            if (this._formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('User is is ${this._user}')
              ));
            }
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: The Query parameter needs to be what the user has typed, is this doing that? Thank you

Comment: I have updated question to show progress, thank you

Comment: I suggest you using `Dio` https://pub.dev/packages/dio#examples. See GET example

Comment: Thanks but the problem is with understanding the TypeAheadField. As the user types the letter 'A' it automatically calls URL and displays results. I need that A value to the place within the URL if you see what I mean. Is there some kind of TextValue paramter I can pull?

Comment: As i said before, the `pattern` is what the user typed. In your example it is `A`. So, you want send to url. As your question, you want like this. `q=london&apikey=x`.
So they are called query parameter. Use Dio, it puts the parameter in url for you.
this `response = await dio.get('/test', queryParameters: {'id': 12, 'name': 'wendu'})` means `response = await dio.get('/test?id=12&name=wedu',)`

Comment: If you insist use `http` package, use `Uri.https('www.myurl.com', '/path/to/url',{"id":1})`. It covert url to `www.myurl.com/path/to/url?id=1`

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand before but now I understand. Thank you very much, for clarity I have used ```$pattern``` as part of URL string.

Comment: Your way is correct, but this way is more clear and easier when you want to use more than 1 parameters in url